Count / Sum JSON variant attribute Flatten
Hi how would I sum the following by the JSON variant column attributes?
Example data:
With Table1 as
ID | ATTR
A123 | {"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}
B234 | {"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}
C567 | {"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}
D019 | {"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}
E923 | {"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y"}

Query: (attempt)
Select xxx as "ATTR_FLAT" , count(distinct ID)
From Table1
group by ATTR_FLAT order by ATTR_FLAT

Desired results:
ATTR_FLAT | count(distinct ID)
ATTR1 | 5
ATTR2 | 5
ATTR3 | 4

I think it can be achieved with FLATTEN, but I haven't been able to figure it out.
Thanks in advance.

using a CTE for data:
with data(id,attr) as (
select $1, parse_json($2) from values
    ('A123', '{"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}'),
    ('B234', '{"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}'),
    ('C567', '{"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}'),
    ('D019', '{"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y","ATTR3":"Y"}'),
    ('E923', '{"ATTR1":"Y", "ATTR2":"Y"}')
)

the main part of the SQL would be:
select f.key, count(distinct d.id)
from data as d
    ,table(flatten(input=>d.attr)) as f
group by 1 order by 1;

giving:

